# Internal server error on css gzip compression

Tags: css, asp.net, compression, gzip, stylesheet

I have renamed .css file to .css.aspx. When I access the file, its loading the page long time and getting internal server error.

The same file I have used in another server its working properly.

what is the issue and how to rectify this issue, Please help.

Server details:
windows server 2013
IIS 7.5
Framework 4.0

Regards,
Sarva